# How can you get the contents of a SVG from a changing URL?

Tags: php, url, drupal-7, file-get-contents

I'm still learning a lot of terminology with php, so I find it hard to find some answer in similar questions. I'm looking to print a custom url into a PHP statement so I can print the contents of an .svg file. I'm using drupal 7.

Below are some examples of what I have tried but the files url keeps being printed?

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("print $fields['field_svg']->content"); ?>
```

or

```
<?php $file=print $fields['field_svg']->content ?>
<?php echo file_get_contents("echo $file"); ?>
```

or

```
$image = file_get_contents($path);

$destination = $fields['field_svg']->content;
$file = file_save_data($image, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

if (is_object($file)) { 
    $file->status = 1;
    $file = file_save($file);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, beach, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: Thanks @fusion3k, better now?